# Magento2 Add review form to custom module

Tags: magento2, custom, review

I need to add review list and form to my custom module ,what should I do ? plz give me some useful method.

https://www.questarter.com/q/magento-2-add-review-form-on-custom-page-10_152353.html

i had try it , but  it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

add in layout

```
 <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" template="companyname_Modulename::form.phtml" />
```

app/code/Companyname/Modulename/view/frontend/form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Review\Block\Form
 */
?>
<div class="block review-add">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Your Own Review') ?></strong></div>
<div class="block-content">
<?php if ($block->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAction() ?>" class="review-form" method="post" id="review-form" data-role="product-review-form" data-bind="scope: 'review-form'">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset review-fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?php __('* Required Fields'); ?>">
        <legend class="legend review-legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("You're reviewing:"); ?></span><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></strong></legend><br />
        <?php if ($block->getRatings() && $block->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
        <span id="input-message-box"></span>
        <fieldset class="field required review-field-ratings">
            <legend class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your Rating') ?><span></legend><br/>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="nested" id="product-review-table">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <div class="field choice review-field-rating">
                            <label class="label" id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control review-control-vote">
                            <?php $options = $_rating->getOptions();?>
                            <?php $iterator = 1; foreach ($options as $_option): ?>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="ratings[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_rating->getId() ?>]"
                                    id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
                                    value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getId() ?>"
                                    class="radio"
                                    data-validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please select one of each of the ratings above.'}}"
                                    aria-labelledby="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label" />
                                <label
                                    class="rating-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $iterator; ?>"
                                    for="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>"
                                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star') ?>"
                                    id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getValue() ?>_label">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? 'stars' : 'star') ?></span>
                                </label>
                            <?php $iterator++; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php endif ?>
        <div class="field review-field-nickname required">
            <label for="nickname_field" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Nickname') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: nickname()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-summary required">
            <label for="summary_field" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Summary') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().title" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-text required">
            <label for="review_field" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Review') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().detail"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar review-form-actions">
        <div class="primary actions-primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit Review') ?></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=product-review-form]": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    },
    "#review-form": {
        "Magento_Review/js/error-placement": {}
    }
}
</script>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used your code, the review submission message is not showing. But when I remove the script from this file. It is working fine. Can you please tell me the use of 
_"[data-role=product-review-form]": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    },_

Comment: @Ramya Would you please check it. code is not added multiple times. means same code is repeated may be the same issue generated

Comment: I have verified the code, the code is not repeated. Now I solved the issue by adding the js file via layout. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

@Ramya ,face same issue

1. how add by adding the js file via layout
2. edit item from cart get error
   "The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again."
   Note : if move review block